# What is the purpose of this space in MACUSA?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

In *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* when Newt and Tina are on the run and joined by Jacob and Queenie, there is a chase in an area of MACUSA which is presumably low in the building and full of pillars.

[image]

**What is the purpose of this space?** It seems to contain nothing but empty space with many lights and many pillars. It doesn't seem to be for storage as it is empty. It's a very large space.

**What is it?**

Comment: Foundations, I expect

Comment: I'm no architect - is it common to be able to access foundations in a large building?

Comment: @ThruGog - maintenance needs to be done somehow, and the bigger the building usually the more complicated the foundation - it's not like you can just pour a thicker slab of concrete and expect it to work.  That said... something like this (simple, geometric, repetitive) is also rather cheap to add to the CGI budget, I expect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are in the **basement**.

> **SCENE 76
>
> INT. DEATH CELL CORRIDOR/BASEMENT CORRIDOR—DAY**
>
> NEWT and TINA, hand in hand, charge through **the basement corridors.**
> Suddenly accosted by the group of Aurors, they turn, darting behind
> pillars, just missing the fired curses and spells.
>
> <sub><sup>[Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them:_The_Original_Screenplay)</sup></sub>

---

This, for example is the basement of the [Cathedral of Our Lady of the Assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathedral_of_Our_Lady_of_the_Assumption,_Oaxaca)

[image]

Comment: Huh. So strange to have such an ornate and empty basement. You're clearly right though.